# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'JpegImageFile'

Tags: python, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I was trying to predict the image with the trained model.
Libraries Imported

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
%matplotlib inline
import os
import random 

import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import cuda,optim 
from torchvision import models,datasets,transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
```

The Code is As Follows

```
Classes = ['Mask','NoMask']

def predict(img, pil=False):
    
    if not pil:
        im = Image.fromarray(img)
        
    trans = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(target_size), transforms.ToTensor(),
                               transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
    im = trans(im)
    im = im.unsqueeze(0)
    im = im.to(device)
    model.eval()
    output = model(im)
#     print(output)
    pred = output >= 0.5
    c = classes[pred.item()]
    return c

img = Image.open('/content/drive/MyDrive/img1.jpg')
ans = predict(img)
print(ans)
```

May I know where i had to change my code to avoid the error i had encountered.

The Traceback I Encountered is
[image]

Comment: Why have you removed the `import` statements - it means we can't be sure which modules you have used. Please click [edit] and put them back.

Comment: and add the entire traceback. basically, do all the things that you'll be asked to do anyway, before anyone has to ask.

Comment: You only opened the file.  You didn’t read it

Comment: @MarkSetchell I had updated the code and included the traceback could you please help me to where i had to change my code.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Could you please suggest the code which i had to write

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I had included the entire traceback which i encountered in the image format.

Answer (score 1):

Your Traceback is incomplete, so I am guessing that the issue is that you have passed a `PIL Image` to your `predict()` function, but it is actually expecting a JPEG-encoded image (i.e. the contents of a JPEG file as it would exist on disk). I think that because your Traceback shows it tries to run `decode()` before crashing.

So, I guess it is expecting the contents of a JPEG file, so try just reading the binary contents of the file rather than opening it into a `PIL Image`:

```
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/img1.jpg'', 'rb') as fd:
    img = fd.read()

ans = predict(img)
```